# Run tmux command if current window is not zoomed using %if

Tags: tmux

According to tmux man page, it is possible to use `%if` to conditionally run its commands. So I am trying to use it to zoom the current pane if it is not already zoomed (otherwise it would un-zoom it).

I tried some variations of

```
%if '#{window_zoomed_flag}' resize-pane -Z %endif
```

without success. Any ideas?

I've seem some examples to achieve what I am trying to do using `if-shell`, but I'd like to do it only with 'native' tmux commands. By 'native' I mean not spawning another process.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the title. About your commend, %if works for me not only in configuration files: it works also pressing ctrl b and then ':'. But not with that variable, and I don't know why.

Comment: _If -F is given, shell-command is not executed but considered success if neither empty nor zero (after formats are expanded)._

It seems you are right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've seem some examples to achieve what I am trying to do using `if-shell`, but I'd like to do it only with 'native' tmux commands. By 'native' I mean not spawning another process.

`if-shell` may or may not spawn a shell. See the description:

> ```
> if-shell [-bF] [-t target-pane] shell-command command [command]
> ```
>
> (alias: `if`)
>
> Execute the first `command` if `shell-command` returns success or the second command otherwise. Before being executed, `shell-command` is expanded using the rules specified in the FORMATS section, including those relevant to `target-pane`. With `-b`, shell-command is run in the background.
>
> If `-F` is given, `shell-command` is not executed but considered success if neither empty nor zero (after formats are expanded).

<sup>([source](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#if-shell))</sup>

Any command denoted `command` is a tmux command, it doesn't need a shell. `shell-command` needs a shell unless `-F` is given. Not every test can be performed with `-F` but in your case it's easy. This will not spawn another process:

```
tmux if-shell -F '#{window_zoomed_flag}' '' 'resize-pane -Z'
```

---

To confirm that `if-shell -F` spawns no additional processes, do the following:

1. Work inside tmux, so tmux server exists. You will need two panes; create them beforehand.
2. Store the PID of the tmux server:

   ```
   pid="$(pgrep 'tmux: server')"
   ```
3. Verify the variable is not empty, just in case:

   ```
   echo "$pid"
   ```
4. Use `strace` to tell if the server creates new processes (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/482656/108618)):

   ```
   strace -e fork,vfork,clone,execve -fb execve -p "$pid"
   ```
5. Select the other pane and invoke:

   ```
   tmux if-shell -F '#{window_zoomed_flag}' '' 'resize-pane -Z'
   # now similar command to unzoom
   tmux if-shell -F '#{window_zoomed_flag}' 'resize-pane -Z'
   ```
6. Observe what `strace` printed. There should be no output.* This means no additional process was spawned.
7. For comparison, these are equivalent commands without `-F`, they do spawn shells:

   ```
   tmux if-shell '[ #{window_zoomed_flag} -eq 1 ]' '' 'resize-pane -Z'
   # now similar command to unzoom
   tmux if-shell '[ #{window_zoomed_flag} -eq 1 ]' 'resize-pane -Z'
   ```

   Each command will make `execve("/bin/sh", …` appear in the output from `strace`.

---

<sup>* Unless you use a hook triggered by a pane being zoomed or resized, and the hook spawns another process. Temporarily remove the hook so it doesn't interfere with the test.</sup>